# How to I connect the toggle buttons to the player in this example?

Tags: javascript

In the attached example, I load BVH and audio data together into a player. It's actually about an animated face that speaks. The example here is comparable. Because voice and animation have to run synchronously, I have to load both before I can play. Now I'm looking for a solution where everything is loaded first, before it can be played. The charging status should also be displayed. Can someone help me? Many Thanks.

```
jsfiddle.net/uj740958/
```

Comment: Um, not sure what you tried doing here, but edit your question so your code is on this site.

Comment: Please read: "*[ask],*" "*[mcve]*" and "*[how do I create 'runnable snippets'?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)"

Comment: I just had a little problem with the fiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution, you can just just use two booleans that switch to true when audio and bvh are loaded, something like :

```
let audioLoaded = false,
    bvhLoaded = false

audioLoader.load( url , () => {
    audioLoaded = true;
    play()
})
bvhLoader.load( url , () => {
    bvhLoaded = true;
    play()
})

const play = () => {
    if(!audioLoaded || !bvhLoaded) return console.log("Not everything is loaded!")

    console.log("Everything is loaded!")
    audio.play()
    video.play()
}
```

EDIT

Okay so I have updated your JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nLvc2www/2/

1. Open your console
2. Click **load_clip_1** or **load_clip_2**
3. Watch "Audio loaded!" then "BVH loaded!" show up in the console
4. Click play
5. Enjoy :)

Comment: ***@Jeremy Thille*** Many Thanks !! David Thomas and Jacque Goupil, that was not nice, a little more consideration and patience should not be a problem, right?

Comment: Yes, of course, I'll do it as soon as it works. I think I needed about 10 or 20 seconds to correct the broken link. Incredible !!

Comment: ***@Jeremy Thille*** I have problems integrating the code so that it runs. Can you show me this with the fiddle example? that would be great !

Comment: ***@Jeremy Thille*** Thank you very much, that looks very good !! However, I still have a problem with the Animation Mixer because it looks a bit different than the example. That's why I've done another fiddle so you can see what this really looks. Do you perhaps see where the problem lies? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qo5nbta/)

Comment: Audio003.mp3") -> Audio003.mp3", I've corrected that, that's not the point.

Comment: This is becoming a whole debugging session :/ If you have another problem, you should write another question.

Comment: Before the changes, it run flawlessly. It can only be on something small. Everything is loading but only the audio is playing. See the comments in the example. [next Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qo5nbta/2/)

Comment: there's a syntax error and your fiddle is broken. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: Ok ? With me the link makes no problems. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qo5nbta/3/)

Comment: No, I can't run it. It says there's a syntax error after `update(); 
 
}); 
});`

Comment: Of course I do not assume that the code I am showing now is running on fiddle. That can not be done this way! It should only show the difference to the first example. It works for me, the only mistake I still have is the ReferenceError: result is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I thought you saw the mistake immediately, if I show it that way.

Comment: ***@Jeremy Thille*** I've done a working fiddle. In it you can see the problem. [Fiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/nLvc2www/4/)

Comment: Yes, there were two errors (open your console, it's telling you this...) `Uncaught ReferenceError: update is not defined` line 162 (I commented this line out) and `result is undefined` line 182 (it should have been `bvhResult`. Now it's working : http://jsfiddle.net/9tp6nr4d/1/

Comment: ***@Jeremy Thille*** Thank you, I noticed that last night and corrected it. But if I use all the code (which is commented out in the example), I still get the error `result is not defined` or `bvhResult is not defined`. I also have to comment out the line if `(! AudioLoaded ||! BvhLoaded) return console.log ("Not everything is loaded yet!"),`  Otherwise I get the error `audioLoaded is not defined`

Comment: This is the solution [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3b9xhu2/3/) Thanks for all @Jeremy Thille